# Rename [singleinstance] to [single-instance]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

[single-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/single-instance) is a nicer name than [singleinstance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/singleinstance), but the former has a lot more instances than the latter. That means I am too lazy to do this manually. I am of course assuming the tag(s) is needed at all (why do we have less than 200 instances of them?).

Comment: A tag synonym can be created for them, if they point the same thing (since I do not know what is single-instance, I can not say they are the same or not). [Tag synonym page is here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms)